# Microsoft Word on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: software-installation

Is there any way to install MS Word or Latex on a Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run Microsoft Word direct on a Raspberry Pi because it is compiled for Intel microprocessors. Raspberry Pi uses ARM processors.

To use **Latex** on a RasPi should not be a problem because it is available from the default Raspbian repository. Just look with

```
rpi ~$ apt list latex*
```

and install the packages what you need.

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice Writer is an open source equivalent to MS Word, and that runs on the Pi. It may be installed by default, but if it's not in the main menu, install it with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice-writer
```

or to install the [whole LibreOffice suite](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice):

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It might do, that's up to the questioner (or anyone who comes across this in future). If the questioner (or anyone else) isn't aware of LO, this could be useful.

Comment: Calling this an "equivalent" is stretching the truth.  I use both for work and there's no credible way to claim that LibreOffice is nearly as powerful as Word. Whether it's a good value is maybe a different issue and depends a lot on what you want to do.

Comment: It's a reasonable suggestion, and it's useful information. If MS Word *did* run on the Pi and I'd answered this way, fair enough, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No to MS Word.  It does not run on Raspberry Pi at all. For latex use `apt-get` and this package: wiki.debian.org/Latex

```
sudo apt-get texlive
```